# Hibernate createNativeQuery using IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate, in-clause

Using Java, Hibernate.

I have a query

```
String pixIds = "1,2,3";
String query = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE PIX_ID IN (:pixIds)";
q.setParameter("pixIds", pixIds);
List<Object[]> results =  q.getResultList();
```

I'm not able to bind this parameter to pixIds using the code above. What is the right way to do this?

Note :  the query I have here is a simplified version of my actual query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following method works
public Query setParameterList(String name, Collection vals) throws HibernateException

Comment: There is no such method for native queries.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate doesn't support binding collection to `IN (...)` in SQL queries.

You need to work the same way as with plain JDBC: given a collection, dynamically generate a query with appropriate number of `?`s in `IN` clause, and then bind elements of that collection to `?`s.

Comment: Sorry I missed adding that pixId's is a string and not a collection. Edited my original post to include the change.

Comment: @sammichy: Exactly the same thing: you need to create three `?`s and bind `1`, `2` and `3` to them with individual `setParameter()` calls.

Comment: I had tried that already and it worked. But the compiled SQL  does not get reused does it? This query is used a lot, so I wanted to see if there is something more optimal.

Comment: @sammichy: There is nothing more optimal, it's an inherent problem with prepared statements.